# What use are multiple phone jacks / DSL (TAE/RJ) boxes?

Tags: networking, router, internet-connection, dsl

I recently moved into a new flat that has [TAE boxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TAE_connector) - the German standard for connecting a router/modem to the external phone / DSL line; I believe the US equivalent would be [RJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack) - in three separate rooms.

From what I read online, it is not possible to connect a router to each of these in order to have internet in each room. It seems that it is also strongly recommended to only use the first TAE box.

My question is: What use are the other boxes? Is there any way I can use them to distribute my DSL connection to the other rooms?

Answer (score 0):

It’s not a standard for DSL, it’s a standard for analogue voice that got used much later for DSL. Those sockets are for phone extensions. You can’t sensibly use them for data, except that you *could* plug your router into an extension socket rather than the master, and it would probably work.

Comment: idk if it's the same for TAE [I've never seen one] but there's good reasoning behind using only the first box for the POTS splitter. There's circuitry in the first box that's not in any extension boxes, that the splitter needs to see. It doesn't make it impossible for extension boxes to work, but the resulting DSL signal will be considerably weaker.